# back button is working on emulator but it is not working in device in android

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-emulator

I'm new to android development. I have index page and I'm displaying every links in the same page using div concept.

Now I want to use the back button for my application. I have developed code to handle the div and it is working in the AVD(Andriod Virtual Device 5556) but if I upload the `*.apk` into my device it is not working.

I'm waiting for your reply. Please help me.

This is my sample code:

HTML Sample code:

```
<div id="photo_playlist">       
    <div id="photo_playlist_home">
        <div class="HomePhotoDetailsBar">
            <div class="innerplay" id="innerrow10833">
                <a style="text-decoration:none;" onClick="player('1');">
                    <div class="thm_image">
                        asdasdasdadadad
                    </div>
                    <div class="video_details_n">
                        <div class="video_details_premium">Premium</div>
                        <div class="photo_details_head">Zoe Duchesne</div>
                        <div class="video_details_premium">5 photos</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="video_arrow">dsfsfsfss</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="detail">
    <div id="playlist"></div>
</div>
<div id="player">
    <div id="photocontainer"></div>
</div>
```

JS Sample:

```
function photos() {
    resetPhotoPlaylist();
    $('#photo_playlist').addClass('current');
    $('#photo_playlist').css('display','block');
    $('#photo_playlist_home').addClass('current');
    $('#photo_playlist_home').css('display','block');
    $('#player').css('display','none'); 
    $('#playlist').css('display','none');
    $('#detail').css('display','none');
    $('#photocontainer').css('display','none');
}

function resetPhotoPlaylist() {
    $('#second_playlist').removeClass('current');
    $('#second_playlist').css('display','none');

    $('#playlist').removeClass('current');
    $('#playlist').css('display','none');

    $('#photocontainer').removeClass('current');
    $('#photocontainer').css('display','none');

    $('#photo_playlist_home').removeClass('current');
    $('#photo_playlist_home').css('display','none');
}

function back() {

    history_.pop();
    var previous = history_.pop();
    if(history_.length==0) {
        history_ = ["home"];
    }

    switch(previous) {
        case "home"     :home();break;
        case "news"     :news();break;
        case "video"        :video();break;
        case "player"       :player(1);break;
        case "gallery"      :gallery(1);break;
        case "photos"       :photos();break;
        case "reader"       :reader(1);break;
        case "searchresult" :searchresult();break;
        case "search"       :search();break;
    }
}

function addToHistory(page) {

        history_.push(page);
}
```

Java Code:

```
public void onBackPressed()
    {
        appView.loadUrl("javascript:back();");
    }
```

Thanks,
Rajeevgandhi. S

Comment: It could help if you show us some code and preferably an example

Comment: ...and it's also nice when you format your code as code. Now your HTML is eaten by this site: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/d16128f6-81ae-4348-b6f7-ea18f6dc0ef3/view-source and have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
appView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { back();})()");
```